# Principal square root of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\sqrt.:= r^{1/2}[cos(\theta/2)+isin(\theta/2)], 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$
define the the particular square root of a complex number.

For what values of z does the equation $\sqrt{z^2} = z$ hold?

I am really sorry, but this question has me stumped and I have no idea how to proceed, hence I couldn't show any working. If someone could please give me a hint.

Comment: The catch is that $z^2 = r^2(\cos (2 \theta) + i \sin (2 \theta)$, but ${1 \over 2} (2 \theta \mod 2 \pi) $ is not necessarily $\theta$ (excuse awful notation).

Comment: So for the equality to hold, $\frac{1}{2} (2\theta)  mod 2\pi$ should coincide with $\theta$?

Comment: Well, you need to be careful with parentheses, but basically yes. Its all about the angle.

Comment: Which is when $\theta$ lies between $0$ and $\pi$? thank you. i got it.

Comment: Again, you need to be a little more precise. You need (using your range of $\theta$ above) $0 \le 2 \theta < 2 \pi$, which gives $0 \le \theta < \pi$.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you for helping out. You have been most kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises when $\theta>\pi$.  Let $\theta =\pi + \delta$ where $0<\delta <\pi$.  Then, we have

$$z^2=r^2e^{i2\delta}$$

on the branch for which arguments are restricted between $0$ and $2\pi$. Then, the square root of $z^2$ is

$$\sqrt{z^2}=re^{i\delta}=re^{i(\theta -\pi)}=-re^{i\theta}\ne z=re^{i\theta}$$

Therefore, the relationship $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ is valid only for $0\le \arg (z) <\pi$.

Comment: Ah thank you! I figured it out with @copper.hat's hint.

Comment: That's good news!  Pleased to hear it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the best vote!  That means a lot to me!  - Mark